# How to get the dimensions of a react-native Child Component

Tags: react-native

I just want to pass a react View inside a component and then I want to find out the dimensions of the passed (as a prop) View in another react Component.
Is it possible to find out the dimensions without using onLayout() means before
rendering the child component.

```
 class Child extends Component {  
   render() {
    return(
     <Parent>
       <View style = {{width: 100}}>
        <View style = {{height: 50,flex:1}}>
        </View>
        <View style = {{height: 30,flex:1}}>
        </View>
       <View>
     </Parent>
    )}  
 }  
 class Parent extends Component {  
   getDimensions(child) {
     // Here I want to find the dimensions of child Component
     // In this use case it should be like height = 80 & width = 100
     // set the state height and width
    }  
   getChildComponent(child) {
     // Here I want to modify the style of Child Component
     var style = [
                   child.props.style,
                   {
                   height: this.state.height + 50,
                   width : this.state.width + 50
                  }];
      return React.cloneElement(child, {style});
    }  
   componentWillMount() {
      this.getDimensions(this.props.children);
    }  
   render() {
    return (
      <View> 
        { this.getChildComponent(this.props.children) } 
      <View>
    )}  
   }
```